# R: Generating dynamic plots from dynamically-generated input fields in Shiny

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm working on a `shiny` app where an arbitrary number of `numericInput` fields are dynamically generated any time a `numericInput` field that appears on page load is updated. The user then can assigns values to these fields and push a button to produce a plot that is a function of those values.

With the help from several [posts](https://community.rstudio.com/t/create-an-arbitrary-number-of-inputtext-elements/64901/2), I've gotten part of the way there. See the below, where I try to let users specify a number of parameters (`n_params`), which should then create that number of `numericInput` fields (`param_fields`). Since the values from those fields should appear in `input`, I then try to extract the values users provide into a vector and summarize them with a histogram.

What is confusing me is why I am receiving an error that argument "value" is missing, with no default" when I run the app and why the plot is not appearing - it seems like the values aren't being saved in the `input` object, but I'm not sure why.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Title"),
  fluidRow(
    
    column("",
           width = 10, offset = 1,
           tags$h3("Filler"),
           
           panel(
             numericInput("n_params","How many fields?", min = 2, max = 100, value = 3),
             uiOutput("param_fields"),
             numericInput("n_sims","How many simulations?", min = 0, max = 100000, value = 10000),
             actionButton("sampling", "Sample from this distribution!")
           ),
           
           tags$h3("Plotted results!"),
           plotOutput("plotted")
  )
)
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Dynamically create a set of numeric input fields based on the
  # number of parameters specified (fancy math symbols needed, ignore mathjax)
  dynamic_list_of_numeric_fields <- reactive({
    n_params <- req(input$n_params)
    purrr::map(1:n_params,
               ~numericInput(paste0("alpha",.), 
                             withMathJax(paste0("\\(\\alpha_{", . ,"}\\)"))))
                          
  })
  
  # Render the parameter fields for user-input of values
  output$param_fields <- renderUI({
    div(
      req(dynamic_list_of_numeric_fields())
    )
  })
  
  # Create plot updated any time sampling button is pushed
  plots <- eventReactive(input$sampling, {
    
    # Get the user-input parameter values
    n_params <- req(input$n_params)
    param_ids <- paste0("alpha", 1:n_params)
    param_vals <- input[[param_ids]]
    
    # Histogram
    hist(param_vals)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plots()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The function `numericInput()` requires a default value for the "value" argument. When you `map()` to generate the numeric input fields you are currently only providing id (ie alpha1) and label (ie 1). Just add a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments by @guasi the issue was that a `numericInput` was missing a default value. Upon supplying this value, it also became clear that I was trying to index reactive values using a vector of values when they can only be indexed by a single string. Accordingly, I use `purrr::map` to operate on the vector of values. Since this produces a list, I unlisted to provide a vector of values to `hist`.

The revised code below produces a histogram as expected.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Title"),
  fluidRow(
    
    column("",
           width = 10, offset = 1,
           tags$h3("Filler"),
           
           panel(
             numericInput("n_params","How many fields?", min = 2, max = 100, value = 3),
             uiOutput("param_fields"),
             numericInput("n_sims","How many simulations?", min = 0, max = 100000, value = 10000),
             actionButton("sampling", "Sample from this distribution!")
           ),
           
           tags$h3("Plotted results!"),
           plotOutput("plotted")
  )
)
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Dynamically create a set of numeric input fields based on the
  # number of parameters specified (fancy math symbols needed, ignore mathjax)
  dynamic_list_of_numeric_fields <- reactive({
    n_params <- req(input$n_params)
    purrr::map(1:n_params,
               ~numericInput(paste0("alpha",.), 
                             withMathJax(paste0("\\(\\alpha_{", . ,"}\\)"))))
                          
  })
  
  # Render the parameter fields for user-input of values
  output$param_fields <- renderUI({
    div(
      req(dynamic_list_of_numeric_fields())
    )
  })
  
  # Create plot updated any time sampling button is pushed
  plots <- eventReactive(input$sampling, {
    
    # Get the user-input parameter values
    n_params <- req(input$n_params)
    param_ids <- paste0("alpha", 1:n_params)
    param_vals <- input[[param_ids]]
    
    # Histogram
    hist(param_vals)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plots()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```