# Operations with dynamically created inputs and functions in Shiny/R

Tags: r, shiny

I need to let the user choose the number of inputs terms and make operations with them and the data (`data_ex`). To do this easily, I created a function too. *But is wrong in something as in print*:

My Shiny App

[image: 1]

The user choose the number of terms in `selectInput("qntt_terms", ...)`.
The terms are serially created with `new_t()` in `output$new_terms <- renderUI({ new_t() })`.
So, I create a function to make a term-by-row multiply and gives a vector: `operation()` that I sum or prod. One central key of this function is that I call the new created variables with `get(paste0("input$term_", i))` to i'th variable. My code:

```
library(shiny)

data_ex <- tibble("col_a" = rnorm(7),
                  "col_b" = rnorm(7),
                  "col_c" = rnorm(7))

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("qntt_terms",
                    label = "Number of Terms",
                    choices = 1:7,
                    selected = 1),
        numericInput("term_1", "Put a Number (1):", 0),
        uiOutput("new_terms")
    ),
    mainPanel(
        fluidRow(
            column(width = 4, "The data to be multiplied row by term:" |> h3(),
                     tableOutput("data_ex_call")),
            column(width = 6,
                     "The Sum with A col results:" |> h3(),
                     textOutput("sum_a_terms"),
                     br(),
                     "The Prod with B col results:" |> h3(),
                     textOutput("prod_b_terms")
    ))
    )
))  # end of the sidebarLayout and fluidPage

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    new_t <- reactive({
        n <- input$qntt_terms |> as.numeric()
        if(n>1){
            lapply(2:n, function(i) {
                br()
                numericInput(inputId = paste0("term_",i),
                             label = paste0("Put a Number (", i,"):"), 0)
            }) # end of the function and lapply
        }     # end of the if(n>1)
    })       # end of the reactive

    output$new_terms <- renderUI({ new_t() })
    
    operation <- function(which_col){
        temp_vect <- vector()
        for (i in 1:input$qntt_terms) {
            temp_vect[i] <-
                get(paste0("input$term_",i)) * data_ex |> pull(which_col) |> nth(i)
        }
        return(temp_vect)
    }

    output$sum_a_terms <- renderUI({
        operation(which_col = "col_a") |> sum()
    })
    output$prod_b_terms <- renderUI({
        operation(which_col = "col_b") |> prod()
    })
    
    output$data_ex_call <- renderTable({data_ex},striped = TRUE,digits = 2) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72960129/r-generating-dynamic-plots-from-dynamically-generated-input-fields-in-shiny/72961001#72961001 The question is not yours but the shiny app does what you're trying to do. Easy to modify.

Comment: Following some suggestions of this issue, I modified my function to this: `operation <- function(which_col){temp_vect <- vector()   for (i in 1:req(input$qntt_terms)) { temp_vect[i] <- req(input[[paste0("term_",i)]]) * data_ex |> pull(which_col) |> nth(i)}return(temp_vect)}` and changed the `renderUI()` to `renderText()` and works!! Thanks!